# Compiling boost without AVX

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

What is the correct way to compile Boost **without** `AVX/AVX2` on a machine that supports AVX?

- OS: Ubuntu
- Compiler GCC 5.4
- Boost version: 1.66

Comment: You probably want to set the GCC option `march` to something other than native.

Answer (score 2):

By default the compiler will generate code that does not require AVX/AVX2, and Boost does not require AVX/AVX2 by default either. So, you don't need to do anything to make the compiled code compatible with CPUs lacking AVX.

Note that this doesn't mean that AVX instructions won't be generated at all. In some places Boost libraries perform runtime detection of CPU features and use AVX only if available. For example, Boost.Log does that.

Comment: Thanks, actually it does ask of AVX instruction even the processor does not support AVX and I am getting illegal instruction error at an AVX instruction inside Boost.Log

Comment: If the compiler generates AVX instructions then it must have been asked to or it contains a bug. First, make sure that the compiler arguments do not enable AVX. You can do that by adding `-d+2` to `b2` command line. If you built the compiler yourself, make sure the default target does not enable AVX. Next, make sure you're not using LTO as it is broken in gcc (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation.html#log.installation.supported_compilers.notes_for_gcc_users).